# Is it possible to change the rate that didOutputSampleBuffer delegate is called?

Tags: ios, camera

I am trying to process the camera frames returned by the callback `didOutputSampleBuffer`, and I want a high frame rate to capture sudden changes in the image (like a flash light going off). The rate at which the callback is called seems to be independent of the frame rate set for the connection. Even if I set frame rate to say 60 via `videoOut.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60);`, the interval between two consecutive didOutputSampleBuffer seems to be around 60 - 80mS (which is a frame rate of around 17 - 12fps. Why is that so? Is it possible to increase it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have found the answer to the question. Basically the frame rate is affected by the preset you use to select the resolution of the image. So for 1MP resolution, you can get a faster frame rate compared to 8MP or and so on. So even if you try to set a minFrameDuration of 160, the hardware gives you what it can based on your resolution setting, which is probably fps of 15 or less.

So to increase the FPS, decrease the resolution along with increasing the minFrameDuration property.